# Windows form: Disable autoscrolling on DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.5

I have a `DataGridView` that I continuously fill adding rows with a `BackgroundWorker`.

The problem is that even though each row is added on the bottom of the `DataGridView` the scrollbar continues to move upwards instead of remaining
on the same spot in which I moved it before.

How can I **disable** the autoscrolling to keep the `DataGridView` on the same spot while new rows are added at the bottom?

Comment: This question has been asked before and has answers: [Save and reset first displayed row](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39935694/6664878) or [Override Rowchanged Event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1521507/6664878)...have you tried either of those?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this with a `ListView` and I am sure a `DataGridView` would work similarly:

```
If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then

    ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count -1).EnsureVisible()

End If
```

This will ensure that your last entry is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DataGridView1_Scroll** event for fetching the specific scroll position. like below -

```
 Dim savedScrollPosition As Integer = 0
    Private Sub DataGridView1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Scroll
    savedScrollPosition = e.NewValue
End Sub
```

Then you can assign this to DataGridView property **FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex** after adding new row. like below -

```
Public Class Form1

Dim i As Integer = 1
Dim savedScrollPosition As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim timer As New Timer()
    timer.Interval = 1000
    AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf timer_Tick
    timer.Start()    
End Sub

Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    UpdateDGV()
    i = i + 1
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDGV()
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Product_Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Product_Price"

    Dim row As String() = New String() {"Product # " + Convert.ToString(i), 1000 + i}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

    'Keep your scrollbar at specific position
    DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = savedScrollPosition

    'keep your scrollbar at bottom of the grid
    'DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Scroll
    savedScrollPosition = e.NewValue
End Sub
End Class
```